# How to make a call of struct in smartPy

Tags: smart-contracts, smartpy

I need to make the following struct call in smartPy.

```
Types.TransferCoin(_strFrom, _toAddress, _assets)
```

The Types.sol files has the following struct:

```
struct TransferCoin {
        string from;
        string to;
        Asset[] assets;
    }
struct Asset {
        string coinName;
        uint256 value;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SmartPy you don't call a structure, you simply create a record.

Two records with the same field names and associated value types are of the same type. Naming a type doesn't make it different and is often not needed thanks to the induce power of SmartPy.

To create a record:

```
my_structure = sp.record(from_=_strFrom, to_=_toAddress, assets=_assets)
```

> Notice that with the legacy sp.record(...) returns an expression that when evaluated will create a record, not a variable with the record inside. If you use `my_structure` multiple times the record will be created multiple type. Surround it by `sp.compute()` to avoid that.

If you want to enforce the type, you have to write the type as explained here: [How do we achieve a variable type of struct in smartPy](https://tezos.stackexchange.com/questions/4757/how-do-we-achieve-a-variable-type-of-struct-in-smartpy) and enforce it.

**With the new syntax:**

```
sp.cast(my_structure, my_record_type)
```

**With the legacy syntax:**

```
my_structure = sp.set_type_expr(my_structure, my_record_type)
```